# How can i disable distributions in Firebase App Distribution

Tags: firebase, crashlytics-beta, app-distribution, fabric-beta, firebase-app-distribution

I'm switching Fabric Crashlytics Beta to Firebase App Distribution and it works perfectly.
when I'm distributing my app in many version like  1.0.2, 1.0.3  and invited to group testers but there were some versions of my app that I don't want group tester to download it's again

In Fabric i can go to setting > app > versions

[image]

If I don't want testers to see some versions I just toggle to disable them.

but in Firebase App Distribution I can't find this feature. I wonder where is it in Firebase

Thank you